# Magento 1 REST API Retrieving Products - attributes in the response

Tags: rest, api, magento, product

I am using rest api products url http://xyc.com/api/rest/products/

It gives only the limited data as response.  I want the entire attribute of the products as the response, and response data is as follows:

```
"entity_id": "3",
"type_id": "simple",
"sku": "PN0495",
"name": "asdfasdf",
"meta_title": "afasdfE",
"meta_description": "afasdf",
"carat_weight": "10.00",
"meta_keyword": "afasdf,",
"description": "adfasdf.",
"short_description": "adfasdf.",
"regular_price_with_tax": 57740,
"regular_price_without_tax": 57740,
"final_price_with_tax": 57740,
"final_price_without_tax": 57740,
"is_saleable": true,
"image_url":"Adfasdf"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your point? @thamizh

Comment: no i dont solve the problem

Comment: Really thank you for your response. May use POSTMAN @ thamizh